# How can I name local leaderboards in Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes?

Tags: mods, keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes

Is there a way to have **local leaderboards** for Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes,
à la retro arcade games?

I play KTANE with several different local casual teammates. Upon completing a bomb, the game's current behavior is to record the best time played on my Steam account. However, this offers no way to keep track of what team made the record. I would prefer to have some way that players can record their names on a local leaderboard.

For a game that centers team play and local play, this seems like it would be a common use case. Despite an active sizeable modding community I have been unable to find any mods or discussion of this topic. I've not had success googling, searching [r/ktane](https://www.reddit.com/r/ktane/), looking at in-game options, or looking at Steam Workshop mods. Is there a mod or workaround that allows for local leaderboards? (i.e., multiple named record entries from a single copy of the game)